# Windows azure url forwarding

Tags: azure

I have a Windows Azure VM that I deployed my website on. I can access my web site with the dns name http://mysite.cloudapp.net but CANT access it through the IP Addresss XXX.XX.XX.XXX. I did a CNAME on this IP address and cant access it with the domain name I bought from the ISP www.MySite.com.
The forwarding would not work if I cant just add the IP address in the url and access the site. what is wrong. Im using the Public Virtual IP Address (VIP) and the endpoint 80 is open

Answer (score 1):

Like Drew points out, you can use a CNAME and have it point to your *.cloudapp.net address (not the IP address). If you want to point to the IP-address you'll have to use an A-record. This is also a supported scenario since the IP-address is assigned to you per deployment:

> With an A record, you map a domain (e.g., contoso.com or
>   www.contoso.com) or a wildcard domain (e.g., *.contoso.com) to the
>   single public IP address of a deployment within a Windows Azure hosted
>   service. Accordingly, the lifetime of this IP address is the lifetime
>   of a deployment within your hosted service. The IP address gets
>   created the first time you deploy to an empty slot (either production
>   or staging) in the hosted service and is retained by the slot until
>   you delete the deployment from that slot. You can discover this IP
>   address from within the Windows Azure Management Portal.

This article will help you with all your custom DNS questions: [Configuring a Custom Domain Name for a Windows Azure Cloud Service or Storage Account](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns/)

Answer (score 0):

A [CNAME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record) doesn't point to an IP address, it points to another DNS name. Therefore you should be pointing your www.mysite.com at mysite.cloudapp.net. IP addresses in Azure are not static (today), that's why you need to use CNAMEs.

Comment: The use of IP-addresses is also supported in Windows Azure, see my answer.

Comment: I have two text boxes on my ISP cpanel of www.mysite.com config. It takes a Name : mysite.cloudapp.net and CNAME : is the IP Address that I can only enter. Which values goes where ?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot in your question?